# Why does in feature embedding the similarities between instances in the new space respects the original pairwise similarities?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

Below is a statement from Machine Learning book, by E. Alpyadin, 4th edition, page 131:

[image]

Question: Why does in  feature embedding  the similarities between instances in the new space respects the original pairwise similarities?

Comment: What's $X$ here? Is it the original instances or is it the embedded instances?

Comment: Original instances